# How to add folders in Source Safe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a static site of html and css files. It has folders on my computers. I see an 'add files' option in Source Safe 8 but it only copies files from the root folder.

How can I get Source Safe to copy the whole folder tree structure and their files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To copy the entire directory tree, create the root folder ("Create Project") in visual source safe. Then from Windows Explorer select all files and folders you want to add to this new project (folder).

It should prompt you for a comment. Enter your note and click `ok`. That should add all files and folders.

If you only need to add a folder, drag the folder in to it's root in VSS. It will create the folder in VSS.

I think VSS always calls folders "projects".

Comment: There must be some sort of option that needs to be set, because this absolutely did not work for me.  It only copies the files in the root of whatever folder I'm dragging and dropping; it doesn't copy all the sub-folders and their contents recursively as I'd expect.

Comment: but are all the files **Checked in** ??

Answer (score 6):

Yes, drag and drop the folder, check the recursive box at the bottom where you add your comment for the initial check in.  This copy all subfolders and files.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with the suggestion of using a better option, however if Source Safe is what you use I believe its in the menus as "Create Project" to manually create folders.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a bit since I've used Source Safe, but IIRC, you should be able to just drag and drop a directory into your Source Safe project and the entire tree will be added.

Comment: You need to also check 'recursive' in the comment dialog but this is a *lot* easier than manually creating projects!

Answer (score 0):

just drag and drop the folder from explorer into the folder in sourcesafe.